# is it possible to start phantoms 2 with spawn?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

As we know phantomjs 2 isn't officially released, is it possible to download an .exe and use `childProcess.spawn('./phantomjs midges.js)` to run phantomjs2, it runs via exec but doesn't when I use spawn. I'm trying to avoid using exec since the phantomjs process returns lot of data back and it's a bad practice to use exec in this case and also that I can't run multiple exec's of phantoms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Here's a minimal example, adapted from node's docs.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    child    = spawn('./phantomjs', ['midges.js']);

child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

child.on('close', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```